Limit of number of Workmail Organizations not clear
I have a project where I need to create thousands of domain names in Amazon Route 53 and it creates an associated mail box with the same domain name in Amazon WorkMail. According to the documentation, there is a default limit of 100 000 domain names per account in Route 53 (and it can be increased). For WorkMail, the default number of organizations (an organization is linked to a domain name) is 100 and it can be increased. But, can it be increased to thousands like Route 53 ? It is very critical to my solution ! And i can't find a proper answer.


Sources:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/adminguide/workmail_limits.html
Quota service in AWS for Route 53

